# How to randomly pickup a location of non-zero pixel in a binary image?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a binary image size of NxMxK. I want to randomly pick up a non-zero pixel location in the image. However, I only can get a tupe of all non-zero pixel. How should I do it using python

I am using

```
location = np.where(array==True)
#Return
(array([ 66,  66,  66, ..., 133, 133, 133]), array([35, 35, 35, ..., 59, 59, 59]), array([102, 103, 104, ..., 105, 106, 107]))
```

My expected is that the pixel location likes (66,35,102) or (66,35,103)... because it is random

Update: This is my current solution

```
ln = np.random.choice (indices[0], size=1)[0]
lm = np.random.choice (indices[1], size=1)[0]
lk = np.random.choice (indices[2], size=1)[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for

```
np.random.choice (location, size=1)
```

Comment: I got an error `  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1122, in mtrand.RandomState.choice
ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional`

Comment: Are you looking for a "black" pixel with all k components =0 ?

Comment: No. In the list of all non-zero pixel, I want to pick up 1 location only.

Comment: I'm lost with your notations, but one of np.random functions will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my current solution using your suggestion